# Is this a pun? (稀/希)

Tags: kanji, nuances, manga

I'm reading a manga in which a character says, 「って稀！」 in response to another character doing something unusual. I understand that 稀 can be translated as "rare," "unusual," etc. However, the character being spoken to in this case is named 希 (reading: のぞみ), which is almost the same as 稀 (and indeed, can share the same reading/meaning).

Is this meant to be understood as a pun, or is it just a coincidence that arises from natural speech?

Comment: What's the name of 希 in kana? まれ? のぞみ?

Comment: @naruto In this case it's のぞみ, edited the question to clarify!

Comment: Can you tell me more about it?
For example, what is the relationship between のぞみ and the character who uses this word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, I don't think this is a pun. To begin with, the character's name is not まれ but のぞみ. 希 is rarely read as まれ in modern standard Japanese.

Still, 稀 is a relatively bookish word, and ordinary speakers wouldn't say "って稀！" to mean something like "That's rare!" in speech. With more context, I may be able to say something more. Either way, the chances of it being a pun are slim to none.